# FileSaver webextension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, filesaver.js

I want to download files from my web extension using FileSaver, I can download through content scripts, but when i try to download at the background.js, it does not work.

This is my manifest.json:

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Logger",
"version": "1.0",

"description": "Captures the interaction between the user and the browser.",

"icons": {
    "48": "icons/logger-48.png"
},

"background": {
    "scripts": ["FileSaver.js", "background.js"]
},

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],
        "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "loggerPlugin.js"]
    }
],

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/logger-32.png",
    "default_title": "Logger",
    "default_popup": "popup/loggerPopup.html"
}
```

and this is the code inside the background.js:

```
function save(){
    console.log("FUNCAOSAVE");
    var blob = new Blob(["Hello, World!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "log.txt");
}
save();
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the browesr console?

Comment: i don't, the script stops. i have no clues

Comment: Please provide more information on what you did, and if possible, attach the complete addon as a ZIP file so I can have a look at it. I tried to reproduce the WebExtension that you have, but I'm unsure where you got FileSaver from, why the content script is important..